# How to convert .py to .exe?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a working python script. I have tried converting it to .exe with Pyinstaller using all options i.e. --onefile, --onedir etc. It creates an exe file though but it doesn't run. When I run it, it just pops up and goes.

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
pyinstaller --onedir myscript.py
pyinstaller myscript.py
```

Nothing seems to be working for me. Please help!
[This is the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llhig.jpg)
 Seems as if some libraries couldn't be imported

Comment: What's in myscript?

Comment: It has following libraries:
pandas, threading, bs4, requests, re

Comment: Try running the .exe from the command line/terminal and seeing what error you get.  If that doesn't help you fix it, add the error onto your question.

Comment: I did as you advised. Updated my questions with the error I got. Thanks

Comment: i don't see any error.

Answer (score 1):

In your cmd window enter 'pip install py2exe'.

Enter this in Python:

print("Hello There!")

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
console=['myscript.py'],
options = {
              'py2exe' : {
                      'packages' : ['pandas']
                      }
              }
)
```

Compile your project by tapping the F5 key.

In my example, I have this:

```
"C:\Users\Excel\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py"
```

It's not a clever name, but it serves the purpose.

In your cmd prompt, enter this: `"C:\Users\Excel\.spyder-py3\untitled1.py"`

You will immediately see the results in the same cmd window, and that's your validation that your program ran!

See the link below for more info.

https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/convert-python-script-exe-0163965/

Comment: Does this work with additional packages such as pandas, numpy and matplotlib?